# Need Help Finding Cause of Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging, crash-reports

So I was running my app on my iPhone 4 without being connected to xcode when it crashed.  I have the crash report but I can't get it to symbolize because of the xcode 4 bug (I've tried the spotlight workaround and replacing the symobicate file but no luck).

Is there any other way I can figure this out? I've tried to replicate the crash many number of times but can't do so.

Here is some of the report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the atos tool, as decribed [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

Comment: Ya but that requires me to have a my appname.app file, which I don't have.  All I have is the xcode project.

Comment: When your project is open, find your .app file in the file list and then right click -> show in finder. Now you have it :)